# C# user input int to array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm asking the user to input 5 numbers and store it into an array so I can send the values in a method and subtract 5 numbers from each array. When I use the:

```
for(I=0;I<5;I++) {
int[] val = Console.ReadLine();}
```

It says I can't convert int[] to int. I'm a little rusty in my programming. I also don't know how to send the array values from the main to the method.

Comment: You need to create the array first, before the loop.  In the loop, read an input, convert it to a number and then set the appropriate array element by index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assigning the string input from the Console to an array of int. This is wrong for two reasons:

1. `int` arrays (`int[]`) are a collection of `ints`.
2. The value you're getting from the Console isn't an `int` and needs to be parsed first.

This is a slight diversion, but I also don't think you should be using an array. Arrays generally have significantly less function in C# than the built-in `List<T>`. (All the rockstars chime in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which)) Some people say there's no reason to use arrays at all - I won't go that far, but I think for this use case it'll be a lot easier to just add items to a `List` than to allocate 5 spaces and initialize values by index.

Either way, you should use `int.TryParse()`, not `int.Parse()`, given that you'll immediately get an exception if you don't check if the user input was parseable to `int`. So example code for taking in strings from the user would look like this:

```
List<int> userInts = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
    int userInt;
    if (int.TryParse(userValue, out userInt))
    {
        userInts.Add(userInt);
    }
}
```

If you'd still like to use the array, or if you have to, just replace `List<int> userInts`... with `int[] userInts = new int[5];`, and replace `userInts.Add(userInt)` with `userInts[i] = userInt;`.

Comment: Actually your code won't compile as your int.TryParse does not actually have the userValue as the argument...

Answer (score 2):

You initialize the array first

```
int[] val = new int[5];
```

and then when you do a for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<val.Length; i++)
{
   val[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Hint: To send the array values from main to the method, just look at how `static void main` is formed:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Meaning main is accepting a string array of of console arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. First initialize your array to have size 5:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

2. Then loop through the array to store each input:

```
    for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

3. Finally, you need to pass your array as an argument to the method.

Note : There are several ways to create a method. 
Visit [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) to know about methods and how they are called from `Main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse the `string` being entered from the console to int first.You accept int by doing:

```
for(int i=0;i<myArray.Length;i++) {

  myArray[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) also works
```

Just like @Furkle said, it is always best to use `TryParse()` which enables you to perform exception handling. MSDN has a nice [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) on this.

Answer (score 0):

furkle is correct, it's not working because the console.ReadLine method returns a string, and you can't assign a string to an int array. However, the solution provided is a bit clunky because it only reads one character at a time from the console.  It's better to take in all the input at once.

Here is a short console program that

- takes in a space separated list of integers from the user
- converts the string to a string List using Split(' ').ToList();
- Converts the string List to an int List
- Reads the contents back to you.

Error handling is included.

```
    static void Main(string[] args){

    var intList = new List<int>();
    string sUserInput = "";
    var sList = new List<string>();
    bool validInput = true;

    do
    {
        validInput = true;
        Console.WriteLine("input a space separated list of integers");
        sUserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        sList = sUserInput.Split(' ').ToList();

        try
        {
            foreach (var item in sList) {intList.Add(int.Parse(item));}
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            validInput = false;
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred. You may have entered the list incorrectly. Please make sure you only enter integer values separated by a space. \r\n");
        }
    } while (validInput == false);

    Console.WriteLine("\r\nHere are the contents of the intList:");
    foreach (var item in intList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\r\npress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    }//end main
```

If you want to make sure the user only enters a total of 5 integers you can do the DO WHILE loop like this:

```
    do
    {
        validInput = true;
        Console.WriteLine("input a space separated list of integers");
        sUserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        sList = sUserInput.Split(' ').ToList();

        if (sList.Count > 5)
        {
            validInput = false;
            Console.WriteLine("you entered too many integers. You must enter only 5 integers. \r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in sList) { intList.Add(int.Parse(item)); }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                validInput = false;
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred. You may have entered the list incorrectly. Please make sure you only enter integer values separated by a space. \r\n");
            }
        }

    } while (validInput == false);
```